# Как починить сломанный JSON, без кавычек у ключей?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть json, в котором есть ключи не в кавычках("), есть регулярка

```
htmlText = htmlText.replaceAll("(\\w+)\\s*\\:", "\"$1\" :");
```

т.е. из

```
name : vasia
```

должно получиться такое:

```
"name" : vasia
```

но, если будет json, где такая строка:

```
"name":"8A Steamy Romance Novel: I'm In Love With a Robot"
```

текущая регулярка сделает так:

```
"name": "8A Steamy Romance "

Novel " : Im In Love With a Robot",
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял, нужно что-то типа "^(\\w+)\\s*\\:"

Comment: Может проще взять первый попавшийся партер json, а дальше уже крутить ключи/значения как хочешь? Или это задание на засыпку?

Comment: по подробнее можете сказать что это? Спасибо

Comment: Там опечатка. Не партер, а парсер. parser. Такая программа, которая занимается разбором всего что подают ей на вход. На выход выдаёт инфу в структурированном виде. Если у вас на входе json, то нужен parser json для java. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: подскажите, если на вход подается сломанный json, то как понять что например в строке ""name":"8A Steamy Romance Novel: I'm In Love With a Robot"";                            8A Steamy Romance - значение, а Novel - следующий ключ?

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю регулярным выражением выделять не ключ, а ключ + значение и обрамлять ключи в двойные кавычки.
Для php регулярка выглядит так

```
 /"?(\w+)"?\s*:\s*(".*?"|\w+)/g
```

-->

```
"$1" : $2
```

Пример тут https://regex101.com/r/rH5qG8/1

Comment: если число будет? Вплоть до отрицательных

Comment: @orion_gm, где будет число?

Comment: в значении
key : -1
Вообще даже может быть так:
key : [1,2]

Comment: @orion_gm, смысл ответа от этого не изменяется: вам нужно выделить одновременно ключ и значение. Чтобы отрицательные числа пропустила регулярка меняем `\w+` на `[\w-]+`, чтобы набор заключенный в квадратные скобки меняем `\w+` на `(\[.*\]|\w+)`